# How to set factory properties so they are independent from one another?

Tags: angularjs

Consider the below Angularjs 'service'. I would like to keep all my 'entries' related variables in this service so I can use them across controllers - as I believe the ideal angular pattern calls for. However, if I manipulate anyone of the variables from a controller - entries, entries_Sorted, entries_Loaded within the service object - they all seem to take on the same new value. I understand the factory object is a singleton but shouldn't these variables be independent?  I don't expect or understand the behavior I am seeing.  How is this useful?  I must be doing something wrong.

To be clear:

If I set local variables within my controllers using this service's return methods, then update those local variables, all the three entries variables within the service will take on the new values.

Service code:

```
  angular.
  module('core.entry').
  factory('Entry', ['$http', 'Topten', 'Stack', 'User',
    function($http, Topten, Stack, User) {


      var entries = [];
      var entries_Sorted = [];
      var entries_Loaded = [];

      var service = {};

   service.getEntries = function(stackId, callback) { 
        return $http.get('stacks/' + stackId + '/entries/')
            .success(function(data) {
                entries = data["entries"];
                Topten.setToptens(data["topTen"]);
                Stack.setOpenStack(data["stack"]);


            callback(null, data);
            })
            .error(function(err) {

                callback(err, null);
            });
      };
      service.returnEntries = function() {
    return entries;
  }

  service.sortEntries = function(callback) {

    // 1. Loop through entries inner looping on toptens - adding topten score to total score
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
      var thisEntry = entries[i];

      var totalScore = 0;

      var toptens = Topten.returnToptens();

      for (var j = 0; j < toptens.length; j++) {
        var thisTopten = toptens[j];
        if (thisTopten["entryId"]) {
            if (thisEntry["_id"] == thisTopten["entryId"]._id) {
              totalScore = totalScore + thisTopten["score"];
            }
          }
      }

      thisEntry.totalScore = totalScore;

        // 2. Add net (likes - dislikes) to entry.totalScore
        for (var j = 0; j < thisEntry.votes.length; j++) {
          var thisVote = thisEntry.votes[j]["vote"];

          if (thisVote == "up") {
            thisEntry["up"] = thisEntry["up"] + 1;
          } else if (thisVote == "down") {
            thisEntry["down"] = thisEntry["down"] + 1;
          }
        }

        var netLikes = thisEntry["up"] - thisEntry["down"]; // one point each
        thisEntry["totalScore"] = thisEntry["totalScore"] + netLikes;
      }

      // 3. Sort entries by entry.totalScore and return 
      entries_Sorted = entries.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.totalScore - a.totalScore;
      });

      callback();
  };

  service.returnEntries_Sorted = function() {
    return entries_Sorted;
  };

  return service;
}
```

]);

My controller's code:

```
Entry.getEntries($routeParams.stackId, function(err, data) {
          if(err) {

          }


          // get sorted entries (after return from getEntries)
          Entry.sortEntries(function() {
            self.entries_Sorted = Entry.returnEntries_Sorted();
            self.loadMore();
          });

        });

 self.loadMore = function() {

      self.entries_Loaded = self.entries_Loaded.concat(self.entries_Sorted.splice(page * increment, increment));
      self.page +=1;
    }
```

Problem: After I call this local 'load_More' function, the properties in my service - entries, _Sorted, _Loaded - will all have the new 'spliced' value.  ie. Entry.entries will have the same value as the controller's local self.entries_Sorted.

Comment: You can't directly edit `entries_Sorted` from your controller since you don't expose this variable itself. You just expose some methods of the factory.

Comment: It's unclear whay you mean by *they all seem to take on the same new value*. The question contains no controller. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . A plunk, etc that can demonstrate the behaviour you're having would be helpful,

Comment: Added more...sorry.  The controller does not access the services properties directly it calls methods to return the values.  If I set local variables using the service's return methods - and I update these local variables the service's properties will update.  I feel crazy saying it.  Must be a singleton pattern I am not groking.